# How to detect successful authentication from Twitter and run some code after that

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am developing an android project in which I have Twitter integration(Using Twitter4j). Here is my code..,.

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        }catch(TwitterException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("Fun");

        return "Run";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String txt) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            txt = null;
        }

        if(txt!=null){
            System.out.println(txt);
                    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                    System.out.println(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

MY PROBLEM IS THAT TWITTER PAGE IS OPEN IN SEPARATE THREAD and "Fun" and "Run" is printed when I am still in Twitter page and when I return after Twitter authentication postexecute is already executed and hence I got null in uri..,.

Can somebody please help me, how can I run some code after Twitter authentication.

OR

Is there any method which run after successful authentication or after error like Facebook onComplete and cancel..,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will start the default browser, which is a separate application. You use a custom scheme in the callback URL and register your app as a handler, so you can get control back to your app, when authorization succeeds. If you want better control, you need to load the page in a WebView and intercept events to get notified. The whole OAuth thing integration is not trivial, but here's an article with an example project that describes is pretty well:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/08/improved-twitter-oauth-android/

Also check other related articles on that blog.